# Procedure error with '&'

Tags: plsql, procedure

[error screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6Efyb.jpg) I am trying to execute the below program in Toad.

```
create or replace procedure tst_excp as
    var_sal number;
    var_empid number;
    var_excp exception;
begin
    select sal into var_sal from emp
    where  empno = &var_empid;

    if var_sal < 4500 then
        raise var_excp; 
    end if;
exception
    when var_excp then
        dbms_output.put_line ('The salary is low');
end;
```

and I am getting an error at the line: **`where empno = &var_empid;`**

error message is:

```
PL/SQL: ORA-00936: missing expression
```

I am planning to pass the value to the variable while executing it.

Answer (score 1):

the `&` is part of the sqlplus (and TOAD, SQL Developer and PL/SQL Developer) runtime variables. it will prompt you on execution (in your case while compiling the procedure) for an input to replace in the code.

if you want the get an input for the procedure, so it will be added to the where clause on every run, you need to receive it as an input variable:

```
create or replace procedure tst_excp (var_empid in number) as -- << changed here
var_sal number;
var_empid number;
var_excp exception;
begin
    select sal into var_sal from emp
    where empno = var_empid; -- << changed here too

        if var_sal < 4500 then
        raise var_excp;
    end if;
    exception
    when var_excp then
    dbms_output.put_line ('The salary is low');
end;
```

Comment: Thank you very much Zohar. It worked for me :-) I had to comment var_empid (3rd line) as it is a duplicate entry now.